# Access Variables from Different Class Method - Java/PostgreSQL

Tags: java, function, class

I am working on a basic Menu Implementation using SQL and Java. I am trying to access a variable `user_name` from my class named `Login`. In the `Login` file I ask users to enter their username, password and other information then select this information from the database to check if they are members of the users_ table. I call some of these functions in the `Menu` file before users are able to access certain options in the menu. However, for some of the menu options I need the `user_name` entered from the users in the `Login` to be inserted into the database for various tables using `INSERT INTO VALUES`.. Is there anyway possible I can do that because when printing out my insertion code my `user_name` field is `null`.
Below you will find the code of the `Login` to get the user_name:

```
 public  String getUser_Name()
 {
    return user_name;
 }

 public void setUser_Name()
 {
    this.user_name = user_name;
 }
```

Here is the code of me trying to access the username in the `Menu` file and a sample SQL statement of me trying to insert the username into another table:

```
  Login user = new Login();
  String user_name = user.getUser_Name();

 // inserting the user_name from Register class
 sql = "INSERT INTO FOR_SALE VALUES(" + "no, "
                   + "'" + user_name + "'" + ", "+
                   "'" + car + "'" +", " +
                   "'" + condition + "'" + ", "
                   + price + ")";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your problem description is too broad and too unclear.  Please show us sample code to illustrate what you are trying to do, and restate your question to be more specific.

Comment: @StephenC Hi! I have edited the question with my sample code!

Comment: You have not restated your question.  So I have answered as best as is possible based on the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem (probably):

```
 Login user = new Login();
 String user_name = user.getUser_Name();
```

Unless there is some "magic" going on, a newly instantiated `Login` object has its `user_name` attribute set to `null`.

You should be using a `Login` object that you got from somewhere else.  From where?  No idea!  You have not shown us the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I may have figured out the issue!